# Getting the size of Menu control in Java SWT

Tags: java, swt

How do I get the height of a menu bar control in a Java SWT shell window?

It seems that different OS has different height for the menu bar at the top of the shell window. So it will be great if I could get the exact height of the menu bar. The menu API doesn't have the getSize() for it.

Comment: Using the Menu height in something doesn't sound right to me. What is your usecase? Probably you are trying to address a problem with a wrong solution.

Comment: You are right. I think I addressed the problem with a wrong approach. Check out Favonius's idea. It worked for me.

Comment: The history of `Menu.getBounds()`: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=38436

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `/*public*/ Rectangle getBounds ()` of the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu`. But the problem is that the method has **the default accessibility**. Its signature suggest it used to be `public` at some prehistoric time. Anyway, there could be many ways to solve your problem:

1. Finding the `height of the shell` and **subtracting** the `height of title area` and `height of client area`. Problem is *`how to find the title area height?`*
2. The second way is as twisted as the first one. **Use** the above mentioned API with the help of java `Reflection`. See the below code for more details. Specially the *`static int getMenuHeight(Menu parent)`* method.

**`Note:`** The **parent** `Menu` parameter should be the **topmost** and the **visible** menu instance. Because, on some OS the hidden submenus are created on the fly. Also, the API is is tested on a Vista machine, running eclipse 3.62 with SUN JDK 1.6_b18.

**`>>Code:`**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MenuTest {

    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Display display = new Display ();
        final Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        final Menu bar = new Menu (shell, SWT.BAR);
        shell.setMenuBar (bar);

        final Composite c = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        c.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,true));

        MenuItem fileItem = new MenuItem (bar, SWT.CASCADE);
        fileItem.setText ("&File");
        Menu submenu = new Menu (shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        fileItem.setMenu (submenu);
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem (submenu, SWT.PUSH);
        item.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                System.out.println(shell.getSize().y -  shell.getClientArea().height);
                System.out.println(getMenuHeight(bar));
            }
        });


        item.setText ("Select &All\tCtrl+A");
        item.setAccelerator (SWT.MOD1 + 'A');
        shell.setSize (200, 200);
        shell.open ();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }

    static int getMenuHeight(Menu parent)
    {
        try {
            Method m = Menu.class.getDeclaredMethod("getBounds", null);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            Rectangle r = (Rectangle) m.invoke(parent, null);
            return r.height;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To get this, you would get the height of the menu bar and title bar, and subtract the height of the title bar.

```
int menuTitleHeight = x.getWindow().getHeight() - x.getWindow().getContentPane().getHeight();
int titleHeight = x.getWindow().getHeight() - x.getWindow().getRootPane().getHeight();
int menuHeight = x.getWindow().getHeight() - x.getWindow().getRootPane().getHeight();
```

Comment: Is this Java SWT? Because I don't see these methods in the Java classes.